# How to solve $\frac{11x+3y}{3x-1}+\frac{5x+2}{3}=9-\frac{3-y}{x-1}=12$ (multiple equality signs)

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions

How to answer an equation with multiple equality signs?

This is the equation:
$$\frac{11x+3y}{3x-1}+\frac{5x+2}{3}=9-\frac{3-y}{x-1}=12$$

I believe it can also be written in this format:
\begin{align}
\frac{11x+3y}{3x-1}+\frac{5x+2}{3}&=9-\frac{3-y}{x-1} \\ \\
\frac{11x+3y}{3x-1}+\frac{5x+2}{3}&= 12\\ 
9-\frac{3-y}{x-1} &= 12
\end{align}
How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$9-12=\frac{3-y}{x-1}$$

$$-3(x-1)=3-y$$

$$y=3x$$

Substitute this into

$$\frac{11x+3y}{3x-1}+\frac{5x+2}{3}=12$$

Solve for $x$, this is just a quadratic problem.

After you solve for $x$, compute $y$ by using $y=3x$.

Edit:

From substitution, we have

$$\frac{20x}{3x-1}+\frac{5x+2}{3}=12$$

Multiply $3$ throughout:

$$\frac{60x}{3x-1}+5x+2=36$$

Multiply $(3x-1)$ throughout, we obtain:

$$60x+(5x+2)(3x-1)=36(3x-1)$$

which is a quadratic equation.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I tried that but end up with a cubic equation.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I've got it! Substituted y = -3x

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake just now, should be $y=3x$.